# Sql: select another field if one field is blank or 0

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have a table Product where i have fields id,name,selling_price and special_selling_price.
I want to fetch "special_selling_price" of all records BUT if

```
`special_selling_price`=0 OR `special_selling_price`=null
```

then it should fetch "selling_price".

If my records are

```
id    name    selling_price    special_selling_price
 1      A           100                   75
 2      B           200                   0
 3      C           300
 4      D           400                  150
```

Then it should fetch

```
75
200
300
150
```

Comment: And this is supposed to run on both MySQL and MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CASE`.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (special_selling_price IS NULL OR special_selling_price = 0)
            THEN selling_price
            ELSE special_selling_price 
       END AS SellPrice
FROM TableName
```

Comment: @CoderofCode I guess it was few sec difference and kumar's answer came first. Let me delete mine.

Answer (score 6):

```
SELECT 
  coalesce(nullif(special_selling_price, 0), selling_price)
FROM product
```

Comment: in every case it is printing selling_price

Comment: @sam yes, you are right, i had reversed the columns. Was too fast

Answer (score -1):

You can use following Query.

```
Select Name, case when special_Selling_Price =0 then Selling_Price
when special_Selling_price is null then Selling_Price
else
Special_Selling_Price end SellingPrice from Product
```